# How does EC2 signal a reboot to an HVM instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, xen

What is the exact signal being sent? How can the instance (Linux in this case) handle it?

Comment: Have you ever initiated a reboot of an instance from the AWS console or API while logged in to it via SSH?  It seems like there's a console message "control-alt-delete" pressed... that's a bit anecdotal, but it seems unlikely that it is anything non-standard.